# PHP (WAMP) OCI8 driver setup problem

Tags: php, database, oracle, driver

Greetings,

I need to install oci8 drivers for PHP, but I’m having some trouble.

I already have a WAMP install, which comes with the oci8 extension, and have done the following in effort to set it up:

1. Enabled the extension by adding the following to my php.ini file in my Apache docroot as a local variable:
   [PHP_OCI8]
   extension=php_oci8.dll
2. Added my extensions directory path to my PATH environment variable on windows (c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/;)
3. Added the same extensions directory to my php.ini file

When I start up my wamp I see the following error message:

1. PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library ‘c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_oci8.dll’

I’m able to verify that the above path is correct, and am tempted to say that there’s something wrong with the .dll, but I’m not sure.

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oracle OCI8 driver also [requires](http://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php) that the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html) 10gR2 (aka 10.2.x) libraries or newer be installed on the machine PHP is running on.  It is recommended you use either the Basic or Basic Lite version depending on if you need the internationalization libraries or not.

[Win32 Instant Client Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)
[Win64 Instant Client Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)

Comment: @wannabenerd:  I have no clue on that one... it might be worth asking another question about, though.

Comment: Looks like this was something in the php.ini file which was edited at some point in the process. Seems like there is a filter that Apache was applying and this was a setting somewhere in the php.ini file. Not sure where it was, but starting fresh from a "clean" php.ini file solved the problem. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

An annotation: I recently had the task of installing PHP 5 on a Windows system with Oracle HTTP Server 10g. PHP <= 5.0 requires an Oracle 8i or 9i client, PHP >= 5.1 requires an Oracle 10gR2 client or above. The Oracle HTTP Server 10g deploys an Oracle 10gR1 client which is not at all supported by PHP 5 (at least on Windows, maybe one can compile by himself...),
but contains PHP 4.3.9 as an Apache module. I couldn't use it: some PHP modules that are required need at least PHP 5.0. 
Solution was: return to Oracle HTTP Server from the 9i companion CD while running a 10gR2 database in a separate Oracle Home.